# Fires with chlorine

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, combustion

could a fire with it's fuel consisting of mostly carbon like coal or wood use chlorine instead of oxygen. My thinking goes that when fire burns it sucks in oxygen and that bonds with carbon to make carbon dioxide. So... if you had chlorine instead of oxygen would the chlorine bond with the carbon and make Carbon tetrachloride instead of carbon dioxide? Would this work or am I missing something?

Comment: See http://www.maybeck.com/firefighting/chlorine/

Comment: @DavidWhite Link shows that chlorine, like oxygen, is an oxidant that can enhance combustion. However, I haven't found an equation for combustion of fuels using chlorine which the OP is looking for. Do you know where they may be found?

Comment: No, and in my 21 years of industrial experience in petrochemicals, I never came across this exact question.  And note - some of that experience was in a chlorine/caustic unit, where the unit was manufacturing chlorine at a high rate.

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for the Chemistry site.